# Run phar file without terminal

Tags: php, composer-php

I am running a shared web hosting and I am trying to run composer.phar but i don't have acces to the terminal. And I asked the provider and said they won't run commands.

I was thinking to run it with some cpanel integrated php package but i have no idea at the moment. I appreciate any idea

Comment: You could run it locally and upload everything (including the vendor-folder), as long as you make sure your environment matches (PHP version, PHP extensions etc). You could also find some hosting that fits your needs better.

Comment: basically phar is a php archive right? so if i will unarchive the phar file and upload them is the same think as running `php composer.phar` ??

Comment: Usually, you should not need to run `composer` on your webserver at all

Comment: so? @NicoHaase what do you suggest? you agree with my `unpack` solution? I need composer to install some dependencies for a plugin

Comment: What do you mean by "unpack"? If you don't have terminal access, how would you run it? Why not install these dependencies on your development machine and properly deploy the application?

Comment: I don't know how to find out what are the dependencies. By "unpack" I meant to unarchive the phar file I have tried this one but it did not work.

This is the error I am getting `Compose autoload not found! Run "composer install" in the root directory of your SourceBans++ installation.`

Comment: "Unpacking" Composer is not needed. Run it on your local system, just like it is documented in their tutorials